# Recorder not working more than once (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare()' on a null object reference)

Tags: java, android

**I've looked around here but none of the solutions I've found work for me.**

Basically, what I'm trying to do is start recording when the ImageButton is held down, stop recording when the ImageButton is released and be able to record again, this time, overwriting the old recording, without first closing the app. When I try to record more than once (hold down the ImageButton again), the app crashes and gives me a:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare()' on a null object reference
>
> at com.myname.audiorecorder.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:86)
>
> at com.myname.audiorecorder.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:61)

This is my code (Both errors have comments with **)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button play;
    private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private String outputFile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    play.setEnabled(false);
    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";;

    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);


    // handles "record" and "stop"
    ImageButton roundButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_button);

    roundButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                vb.vibrate(50);
                Log.i("Touched", "Recording");
                startRecording(); // ** ERROR (MainActivity.java:86)
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                stopRecording();
                Log.i("Released", "Stopped");
                vb.vibrate(50);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    // play recording
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException,SecurityException,IllegalStateException {
            playRecording();
        }
    });
}


// start recording voice
public void startRecording()
{
    try {
        myAudioRecorder.prepare(); // ** ERROR (MainActivity.java:61)
        myAudioRecorder.start();
    }

    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


// stop recording voice
public void stopRecording()
{
    myAudioRecorder.stop();
    myAudioRecorder.reset();
    myAudioRecorder.release();
    myAudioRecorder  = null;

    play.setEnabled(true);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


// play recorded voice
public void playRecording()
{
    MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        m.setDataSource(outputFile);
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        m.prepare();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    m.start();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Any ideas as to what is going on? I've tried some solutions I saw here and a few I came up with on my own but nothing worked. Thank you very much.

---

**EDIT**

Here's the rest of the error in the logcat

> at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8470)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2407)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
>
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
>
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
>
> at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2752)
>
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
>
> at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8671)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4193)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4059)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3604)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3657)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3623)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3740)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3631)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3797)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3604)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3657)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3623)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3631)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3604)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5912)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5851)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5822)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6002)
>
> at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
>
> at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>
> at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

Comment: In the `stopRecording()` method, you set `myAudioRecorder = null`, but you never re-initialize it when calling `startRecording()` again.

Comment: You're missing what caused your error. Your stacktrace is incomplete. Provide the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising AudioRecorder in oncreate. This means Instance will be created when you open that activity. So better is Initialize AudioRecorder on ClickListener, so when you click on ImageView each and every time new Instance will be created.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize AudioRecorder before calling startRecording() inside onTouch(), otherwise the second time you call it it will be null because your setting it to null after releasing it inside stopRecording();